# How to use OpenCV to create binary mask of images?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing

I want to create a binary mask of an image using Opencv.

https://img.techpowerup.org/201105/019590-0.jpg and convert this to

[image: Text]

How to do this using OpenCV ?
I tried running this code block

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# load image with alpha channel
img = cv2.imread('019590_0.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# extract alpha channel
alpha = img[:, :, 3]

# threshold alpha channel
alpha = cv2.threshold(alpha, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# save output
cv2.imwrite('object_alpha.png', alpha)
```

But this is giving an error : `IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 2 with size 3`

Answer (score 1):

Indexing in Python starts from 0 so your line should be:

```
alpha = img[:, :, 2]
```

Also your thresholding is not doing anything as you are using 0 for the threshold value, try increasing it until you get something closer to your expected output.
I tried running your code using the image you uploaded but it got converted to jpg and artifacts appeared so it wasn't possible to get your desired results.

Comment: I tried this but this gives a blank white image as output :(

Comment: it means that your alpha value is the same for each pixel, you would need to mask the image with the background color then.